# Does Oracle remove trailing decimal places for Number datatype if all decimals are 0?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

We are migrating our application's database from Oracle to Postgres. We have observed some strange behaviour during the testing of our application connected to the new Postgres database and an external downstream consumer application. The high level application flow is as such:

1. Our app writes a row to one of the tables
2. Our app reads the row from the table into a java object
3. Our app parses this object into an XML which is then sent on a queue
4. Third party app consumes this message from the queue and processes it

In our Oracle database there is a table with a column called `AMOUNT` that is defined as `NUMBER(18,2)`. We have migrated this column in the Postgres database to `NUMERIC(18,2)`.

The problem we are observing, is that after the migration the third party app cannot process the new messages because the AMOUNT field in the XML is now formatted like `3000.00` while they were expected `3000`. They don't expect any decimal places.

I have done some investigating and discovered that this is because in the Oracle DB, when we write `3000.00` it is actually being stored as `3000`, and sent as such to the downstream app. However when we write `3000.00` to Postgres, it is actually stored as `3000.00`, and then retrieved like that by our application.

I cannot find any documentation to say that Oracle truncates the decimal place when they are Zeros, but this is the behaviour I'm observing. Is this expected behaviour by Oracle? If we insert `3000.01` into the Oracle database, it is stored like that. It only seems to truncate the decimal places when they are `.00`

Comment: PostgreSQL also truncates float numbers when have zeroes to the right of the decimal point in any of floating point types (numeric, decimal, float).

Comment: If your column is NUMBER(18,2), Oracle will preserve two digits after the decimal. It is not truncating. More likely your issue is in your app, your XML parsing, or somewhere else into Postgres. As for your testing you are probably seeing behavior controlled by your database client software. Various programs out there may choose to auto-hide the decimal portion if it gets a .00, but that's your client program, not Oracle doing that.

Comment: It is unclear if your problem is storing the data or in displaying the data in XML format. You have not included any code in your question which makes it impossible to debug. Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE].

Answer (score 0):

This is a presentation problem, not a data storage problem. Both Oracle and PostgreSQL store the full scale and precision as per the column's definition; however, when the value is converted to text without a specified format, the presentation is implementation specific. Since it appears that the downstream app expects an integral value, then prior to generating the XML, either cast `AMOUNT` to `bigint` or explicitly format it; e.g., `AMOUNT::BIGINT` or `TO_CHAR(AMOUNT 'FM999999999999999990')`.

Comment: But in that case, it makes no sense to me why this error is occurring. I've tested the exact same codebase running against both databases. When the code runs against Oracle, it retrieves the value and sends it as `3000`, while when run against Postgres, it retrieves and sends `3000.00` We've checked the Oracle database with SQLDeveloper, which is showing the value is stored as `3000`. So are you saying that SQLDeveloper GUI is what is removing the `.00`? I don't understand why it would do that

Comment: also just to add some extra info, I've queried both databases from DBeaver as well, and again when querying the Oracle database the value is displayed on its GUI as `3000` and from the Postgres database it is displayed as `3000.00`. So I'm having a very hard time not believing this is Oracle removing these decimal places.

Comment: Also, in our calling java code to retrieve the value from the database, we are reading this value into a `BigDecimal`, which when read from Postgres gives the value `3000.00`, but when read from the Oracle DB gives `3000`....

Comment: As I recall, Oracle's default conversion of numeric types to text is equivalent to using `TO_CHAR` with `TM9` as the format specifier; i.e., only the minimum number of characters required to represent the value are used. The default conversion to text in PostgreSQL is the minimum number of characters required to represent the value and its precision. Whether querying with SQLDeveloper, DBeaver, Java, or some other client, the value seen by the client comes from the DB driver. The visible representation is a combination of client and driver transformations.

Comment: Ok that's interesting and good to know. I can understand that then why I'd see this issue with clients like SQLDeveloper and DBeaver. But I don't see how that could happen with java, since I'm not reading the value as text, I'm reading it into a `BigDecimal` which should include the precision. I'll have to investigate this further, and try to make a reproducible example, which is easier said than done